# exploding a file name to separate the name and extension won't work in PHP?

Tags: php, filenames, explode, period, scandir

I'm building a class that returns an string that will include files in a folder automatically, kinda like a loader for an HTML file.

Here's the method that will be called:

```
function build_external_file_include($_dir){
    $_files = scandir($_dir);
    $_stack_of_file_includes = "";//will store the includes for the specified file.
foreach ($_files as $ext){
    //split the file name into two;
    $fileName = explode('.',$ext, 1);//this is where the issue is.

    switch ($fileName[1]){
        case "js":
            //if file is javascript
             $_stack_of_file_includes =  $_stack_of_file_includes."<script type='text/javascript' src='".$dir.'/'.   $ext ."'></script>";

            break;
        case "css";//if file is css
             $_stack_of_file_includes =  $_stack_of_file_includes."<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"".$dir.'/'. $ext."\" />";
            break;
        default://if file type is unkown
             $_stack_of_file_includes =  $_stack_of_file_includes."<!-- File: ".  $ext." was not included-->";
    }


}
return $_stack_of_file_includes;
}
```

So, this runs without any errors. But, it doesn't do what it's supposed to do... or at least what I intend it to do. Technically speaking here,

`$fileName[1]` should be the extension `js`

`$fileName[0]` should be name of the file `main`

but

`$fileName[0]` is `main.js`.

does explode not recognize `.`?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Change `$fileName = explode('.',$ext, 1);` to `$fileName = explode('.',$ext);`

Comment: i'll suggest you to use [`pathinfo()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) instead of explode

Comment: @felipe.. what will you with these filenames `jquery-.1.7.1.min.js`

Comment: diEcho, hi, thank you for your interest! This particular class builds a set of HTML external file references for CSS and JS files. As you can see here, the script is set to loop through files in a specified directory and return a string that has HTML tags that reference external files, in this case the files in that folder.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're forcing your resulting array to have 1 element, which causes it to have the entire filename.

```
explode( '.', $ext, 1 )
```

should instead be

```
explode( '.', $ext );
```

Proof: http://codepad.org/01DLpo6H

Comment: wow, I feel so stupid right now. I can't thank you enough though.

Answer (score 0):

You've limited the explode to producing **1** array entry, so it can never do anything:

```
print_r(explode('.', 'a.b', 1));
Array
(
    [0] => a.b
)
```

The limit should be at least 2. or, better yet, you should be using the [pathinfo()](http://php.net/pathinfo) function, which properly handles filename components for you.